# Sqlite confused while using getter and setter to send SELECT query data

Tags: android, sqlite

Getting little confuse while using getter and setter on sqlite because I am new  to sqlite and I feel it very complicated. I have various datas in my database and I want to send these data to another class. How can I do that? I tried something like below but I am stuck I don't know what the another code would be? someone help me  please!!

**Encap.java**

```
public class Encap {
int _id;
String _phoneno;
String _Msg;
int _year;
int _month;
int _day;
int _hour;
int _minute;

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_phoneno() {
    return _phoneno;
}

public void set_phoneno(String _phoneno) {
    this._phoneno = _phoneno;
}

public String get_Msg() {
    return _Msg;
}

public void set_Msg(String _Msg) {
    this._Msg = _Msg;
}

public int get_year() {
    return _year;
}

public void set_year(int _year) {
    this._year = _year;
}

public int get_month() {
    return _month;
}

public void set_month(int _month) {
    this._month = _month;
}

public int get_day() {
    return _day;
}

public void set_day(int _day) {
    this._day = _day;
}

public int get_hour() {
    return _hour;
}

public void set_hour(int _hour) {
    this._hour = _hour;
}

public int get_minute() {
    return _minute;
}

public void set_minute(int _minute) {
    this._minute = _minute;
}

}
```

**AppalaHelperAdapter.java**

```
  public List<Encap> getAll(){
    List<Encap> Encapli=new ArrayList<Encap>();
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db=appalaHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={appalaHelper.UID,appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER,appalaHelper.MESSAGE,appalaHelper.YEAR,appalaHelper.MONTH,appalaHelper.DAY,appalaHelper.HOUR,appalaHelper.MINUTE};
        Cursor cursor=db.query(AppalaHelper.TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        Encap encap=new Encap();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            encap.set_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.UID)));
            encap.set_phoneno(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.PHONE_NUMBER)));
            encap.set_Msg(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.MESSAGE)));
            encap.set_year(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.YEAR)));
            encap.set_month(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.MONTH)));
            encap.set_day(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.DAY)));
            encap.set_hour(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.HOUR)));
            encap.set_minute(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(appalaHelper.MINUTE)));

            Encapli.add(encap);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return Encapli;
}
```

Now, Is that above code correct? How do i call this from anotherClass?

**Another.class //where  I need data from database**

```
//I dont know how the List<Encap> are called.
//I only know to  call single values like String data=appalaHelperAdapter.getAll(); and use the return string data to other
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do mean by `How do i call this from anotherClass`

Comment: I do not understand you very well. you want get all records in a table in the database in Another.class?

Answer (score 1):

I have not read all of you code but you are reading from DB, correct?
Then

```
SQLiteDatabase db=appalaHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

should be

```
SQLiteDatabase db=appalaHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: No, Writable and Readable not makes any sense. I am trying to get all row from database and use those values in another class when it needs. sorry for my poor english :(

Comment: OK, what is the problem?, I don't see something wrong, if the query has returned data the while loop  will work!

Answer (score 1):

If the `AppalaHelperAdapter` is your class for database you just create an object of this class and `variable = new AppalaHelperAdapter(context);` and then you just call the method in question.